# Socket Println never sending data

Tags: java, android, sockets, xamarin.android

I have code on an android (Xamarin) device as such:

```
socket = new Socket();
        socket.Connect(new InetSocketAddress(IP_ADDR, PORT));
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.InputStream));
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.OutputStream, true);


        string userInput = "";
        while ((userInput = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            writer.Println(userInput);
        }
```

The server side is a Windows server.  I am reading data fine.  But Println is never sending the data.  I have tried .Flush() afterward, to no avail.  I even considered possible newline differences and changed the code to just .Print() with 13 and 10 after, then a flush. Still nothing.  Any thoughts? TIA

Comment: This is not valid Java code.

Answer (score -1):

Moments later, I discovered the answer.

Instead of 13, 10, I send the char representation, ala:

```
writer.Print(userInput);
writer.Print('\r');
writer.Print('\n');
writer.Flush();
```

Comment: `println()` already does exactly this, assuming you are indeed talking about `println()`, and Java, which isn't clear from either your question or your answer.